# Variable assignment in C vs scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to C and I have a small problem in understanding this `scanf()` line:

```
printf("Enter a message to add to message queue : ");    
scanf("%[^\n]",sbuf.mtext);
```

How do I write this statement if I am getting the value from the command line?
I think I would have to declare the variable as a string?

Comment: The variable would have to be declared *anyway*? And strings are copied with [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) (or [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), depending on circumstances). The command line is passed to your program as parameter to `main()` -- e.g. `int main( int argc, char * argv[] )` gives you access to the tokens of your command line as elements of `argv[]`.

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: If you are "getting the value from the command line" it will be in the `*argv[]` array.

Comment: chr msg[50];
strcpy (argv[1], argv[2]);

like this?

Comment: Thanks Dev Solar and Weather Vane... it worked.. I think I need to take some rest.. my brain is not working

Comment: `if(argc > 1 && strlen(argv[1]) < sizeof msg) { strcpy(msg, argv[1]); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting any value or data from command line then the [**command line arguments**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html) *(click to open link)* are very helpful

---

for using command line arguments, you must change you `main()` function definition from, let's say `int main()` to

`int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )`

here `int argc` is the ***argument counter***. It is an integer and stores the number of arguments passed from the command line *(+ the name of the program)*

and `char* argv[]` is the ***argument vector*** which holds the data you sent into main function as strings

---

> How do I write this statement if I am getting the value from the
>   command line?

As any value you entered at command line is stored in `char *argv[]`, you can access the appropriate string this way

```
 printf("%s",argv[command_no])
```

---

**Example :** *(printing out value of `argc` and all strings stored in `*argv[]`)*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Command line arguments :**

```
 these are command line arguments :)
```

**Output:**

```
6
E:\C-Programming\Workspace\Interview\Debug\Interview.exe
these
are
command
line
arguments
:)
```

> **Note :** The first argument or the `argv[0]` is always the name of the program